# Referring to all objects from a same class

Tags: java, android

I am designing an app which contains 81 tiles arranged in a 9*9 square. Once clicked, a tile will have a method to execute. Then, the 8 surrounding tiles too. How can I dynamically know which tiles are the surrounding? I was thinking of assigning coordinates (two integers x and y) to each tile informing of its location in the square. Is there a way to know which tile has x=4 and y=7 for example?

Comment: Store them in a 2D array, then you can refer to them by their coords.

Answer (score 0):

You could store all of the tiles in a 9x9 array that is stored publicly and pass the i and j position of a specific tile to it. When a tile is clicked you can call a global method that takes the i and j of the tile you clicked and run a method on each of the surrounding tiles.

```
public Tile[] tiles = [[tile1,tile2,...],[row2...],...[row9...]];

public void triggerTiles(int ith, int jth) {
    for (int i = ith - 1; i <= ith + 1; i ++) {
        if(i < tiles.length && i >= 0) {// check if we are in bounds
            for(int j = jth - 1; j <= jth + 1; j ++) {
                if(j < tiles[i].length && j >= 0) {// check if we are in bounds
                    if(i != ith && j != jth) { //If not the center tile
                        tiles[i][j].callMethod();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```